# Bold citations with page number

Tags: citing, natbib, bold

I'm trying to change all of my citation call-outs into bold font. I found similar questions where the where a simple macro was used to change the `\citep` and `\citet` commands. However, while this works for simple examples, it does not work when I add an extra argument for the page number.

Here is the basic example which works

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\let\oldcitet\citet
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{\textbf{\oldcitet{#1}}}

\begin{document} 

\mainmatter 
Citet with a single argument gives \citet{mullins_16} as a result.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bibliography_PhD_thesis}

\end{document}
```

where the file bibliography_PhD_thesis contains the item

```
@article{mullins_16,
    Adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
    Adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.459.2882M},
    Archiveprefix = {arXiv},
    Author = {{Mullins}, A.~M. and {Loughnane}, R.~M. and {Redman}, M.~P. and {Wiles}, B. and {Guegan}, N. and {Barrett}, J. and {Keto}, E.~R.},
    Doi = {10.1093/mnras/stw835},
    Eprint = {1604.03059},
    Journal = {{MNRAS}},
    Keywords = {line: profiles, molecular data, opacity, radiative transfer, ISM: molecules, submillimetre: ISM},
    Month = jul,
    Pages = {2882-2892},
    Title = {{Radiative transfer of HCN: interpreting observations of hyperfine anomalies}},
    Volume = 459,
    Year = 2016,
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stw835}}
```

for the citation. This results in

[image]

for a simple citation, as I want.

If I change the macro to

```
\let\oldcitet\citet
\renewcommand{\citet}[2]{\textbf{\oldcitet{#1#2}}}
```

Then for a simple citep, then it returns a ? and removes the next character after the command

[image]

If I add the page number to my text such that

```
Citet with a page number gives \citet[p6]{mullins_16} as a result.
```

then I can't create the latex file and end up with following error

[image]

Do any of you know how to modify the citet command such that it is in bold and allows for a page number argument? If there is no other way I could manually put the few commands with a page number in bold, but I would like to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: You probably want `\renewcommand{\citet}[2][]{\textbf{\oldcitet[#1]{#2}}}`.

Comment: @gusbrs -- The `natbib` package defines `\citet` and `\citep` as taking up to two optional arguments. Your suggestion would clobber the ability of these macros to take 2 optional arguments, and would limit them to take just one optional argument. Of course, that's still better than the OP's suggestion, but not perfect either.

Comment: @Mico I didn't know that, and was just working "within the OP's logic". Thanks for pointing that out. So, I take my suggestion back, there's certainly a better way to handle this, which I leave to those better acquainted with `natbib`.

Comment: Please tell us whether you need to preserve the ability of the `\citet` and `\citep` commands to take up to two optional argument, or if you're ok with them being reduced to taking a single optional argument. A second issue: Consider the instruction `\citet[pp.~15--17]{mullins_16}`: Should the `pp.~15--17` sub-string be typeset in bold as well, or just the author ("Mullins et al") and year ("2016") sub-strings? Please advise.

Comment: @gusbrs - I've gone ahead and posted a comment, to ask the OP directly which parts of the existing syntax of `\citet` and `\citep` should be preserved. Let's see how the OP responds.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I only occasionally use one of the optional arguments for the page number, alongside the citekey. I'm only looking to change the author and year to bold. For context, I'm trying to change the colours of the hyperref package to bold black, so that links still stand out while avoiding having most of my 340 pages count as colour for printing purposes.